# NetSuite request.getBody() returns empty string

Tags: forms, post, netsuite

I'm calling `request.getBody()` in a POST request inside NetSuite. However, I'm returned an empty string. I've tried `request.getAllParameters()` as well and get a list of nulls. The only way I have of accessing the posted parameters is using `request.getParameter(parameter_name_here)`, which is odd as this should only work with a GET request. Also, I've confirmed that the post method is 'POST' and the form fields have name attributes. Any ideas?

Code example:

```
function suitlet(request, response){
    var _post = request.getBody();
    //_post should be a stringified representation of the request post
    //parameters but is empty string.
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code of what you have tried?

Comment: Updated original post with code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As per NetSuite in POST request within suitelet, to read parameters you need to use `getParameter` itself.

Whereas `getBody` is only available in the return value of a call to `nlapiRequestURL`.

For further clarification you can check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3109660.html) out.